# storing db contents in array PHP

Tags: php

I am not sure how to do this, but if it can be done can anyone please help me in this.
Basically I have 3 columns in my table:

```
ID Set   Result Case  
1  Set1  PASS   101  
2  Set2  FAIL   102  
3  Set2  FAIL   101  
4  Set1  FAIL   101  
5  Set1  PASS   104  

$set =  $row['Set'];
```

What I am trying to achieve is , foreach of these `Set`, store its associated `Result` and  `Case`  in an array.

Comment: You say you have three columns, but you show four?  Also, where is $row defined? And in $row['Set'], is 'Set' intended as a literal, or are you using it as a placeholder?

Comment: @Dathan: $row is from mysql_fetch_array and I am using $set as placeholder for that corresponding $row['Set'] value

Comment: do us a favor, will you? Are you familiar with print_r? If so, can you write out what you want the final result to be, were it printed out using print_r?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($records as $key => $value)
{
    $arr[$key]['Result'] = $value['Result'];
    $arr[$key]['Case'] = $value['Case'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

In light of your comment:

```
foreach ($records as $key => $value)
{
    $arr[$key][$value['Result']] = $value['Case'];
}
```

In light of your most recent comment:

```
foreach ($records as $key => $value)
{
    $arr[$value['Set']][$value['Result']] = $value['Case'];
}
```

Comment: But is it a 2 dimentional aray, I thought I would require a 3 dimentional array.
[Set][Result][Case] ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with his table, and $arr is almost identical to $set in the end. If this _is_ what he's looking for I think it would be a little clearer to instead unset() those array elements he doesn't want ('Set' and 'ID')

Comment: What is "required" is the wrong way to think about it.  We don't know the hierarchy of your data, we only see it in it's relational form. *YOU* choose what it's going to look like when you structure it into an array.  Want it in a 2D array? Do that! Want it in a 3D array? Do that!

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: It's not identical, check his comment.

Comment: Why the down-vote? The question is a little ambiguous but it seems to do what the asker is asking.

Comment: @JPro: Check again, you would benefit from being explicit about your question in the first time.

Comment: @Alix Axel I didn't down vote but would if I had the points, as your third answer will cause him/her to lose data (see my answer).

Comment: @sequoia mcdowell: Potentially, but I just provided the solution he wanted, I'm not making assumptions about his data - that's up to him to decide.

Answer (score 2):

After reading comments I thought I'd take a crack at it.

First of all: What you asking for will not work unless you are going to check for duplicate {result} keys in `$array[Set2][{result}]` and lowercase them if there are duplicates as in your comment, which I don't know why you'd do.  It would be confusing and strikes me as nonsensical. To wit:

`$arr[Set2][FAIL]` vs. `$arr[Set2][fail]`

If you do it as shown above [in Alix Axel's third code block], you'll do:

`$arr[Set2][FAIL] = 102` then overwrite that array index value with `$arr[Set2][FAIL] = 101`, causing you to lose data.

To put it another way, you are using a combination of the "set" and "result" as a "combined key" so to speak, which you CANNOT DO as the combinations are not unique (Set2 FAIL, Set2 FAIL).  I know it's an annoying answer, but you should take a look at what you are doing and why, as I have a hunch you are going about it the wrong way. You probably want an array like:

```
Array
(  
    [Set1] => Array
    (  
            [101] => 'FAIL'  
            [102] => 'PASS'  
    )

    [Set2] => Array
    (  
            [101] => 'FAIL'  
            [102] => 'FAIL'  
    )
)
```

or something, but even then it won't work as you have some Set/Case pairs both passing and failing.  Because of this, the only thing you can do here is use the "id" as an index:

```
Array
(  
    [1] => Array
    (  
            [Set] => 'Set1'  
            [Result] => 'PASS'  
            [Case] => '101'  
    )
    [2] => Array
    (  
            [Set] => 'Set1'  
            [Result] => 'FAIL'  
            [Case] => '101'  
    )
)
```

But I can't even tell you how to do that, cuz you haven't told us how your query results array is structured in the first place!! So step 1) Please print_r or var_dump the query results.

Comment: +1 for the alternative approach. Hope you don't downvote me now! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming
$myArray = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Set ASC");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($rows); $i++) {
    $myArray[$rows['ID']]['Set'] = $rows['Set'];
    $myArray[$rows['ID']]['Result'] = $rows['Result'];
    $myArray[$rows['ID']]['Case'] = $rows['Case'];
}

// output
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Set] => 'Set1'
        [Result] => 'PASS'
        [Case] => '101'
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [Set] => 'Set1'
        [Result] => 'FAIL'
        [Case] => '101'
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Set] => 'Set1'
        [Result] => 'PASS'
        [Case] => '104'
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [Set] => 'Set2'
        [Result] => 'FAIL'
        [Case] => '102'
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [Set] => 'Set2'
        [Result] => 'FAIL'
        [Case] => '101'
    )
)
```